# Compare two tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in my SQL Server, both tables has the same columns. I need find the differences between this tables.

The tables (all fields are in nvarchar format):

[image: Format of the two tables, all fields are in nvarchar format]

following the tables columns, i need make an SQL query to indentify this conditions:

```
table1.uf = table2.uf, 
table1.municipio = table2.municipio, 
table1.marca_modelo = table2.marca_modelo, 
table1.ano_fabricacao = table2.ano_fabricacao
table1.qtd_veiculos != table2.qtd_veiculos
```

and

```
`Unique lines in table1`
```

I've already tried make this query (bellow) but doesn't work.

```
Select *
from Table1 J left join
     Table2 M on J.uf = M.uf 
          and J.municipio = M.municipio 
          and J.marca_modelo = M.marca_modelo 
          and J.ano_fabricacao = M.ano_fabricacao 
          and J.qtd_veiculos != M.qtd_veiculos
```

Can you help me with that question?

I expected to receive the following result:

[image]

The fields in red show the differences between tables and in the last line,  in Table1 not have any correlation in Table2.

I apologize for the lack of information, this is my first topic here in the forum. but thanks for the help!

Comment: How does your query "not work"?  That is a rather vague description.

Comment: If you want the comparison to work both ways, you should use a full outer join.

Comment: What does not "work"? Please elaborate.

Comment: the conditions... should they be combined with an `AND` operator, or an `OR`, or something else? Is that the reason it is not working?

Comment: Paste your data as text - not as image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script I use to compare two tables.  Perhaps you can modify this for yourself by throwing the results into a temp table for further analysis. 
You could change the '*'s to list only those columns you want to compare.

```
--  Thisc script compares any two tables.  
--  Enter the two tables names to compare in the first two lines.  

DECLARE @table1 NVARCHAR(80)= 'my_first_table_to_compare'
DECLARE @table2 NVARCHAR(80)= 'my_second_table_to_compare'
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR (2000)

SET @sql = '
SELECT ''' + @table1 + ''' AS table_name,* FROM
(
SELECT * FROM ' + @table1 + '
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM ' + @table2 + '
) x

UNION 

SELECT ''' + @table2 + ''' AS table_name,* FROM 
(
SELECT * FROM ' + @table2 + '
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM ' + @table1 + '
) y
'

EXEC sp_executesql @stmt = @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question, so this is a [wild] guess. You want to find:

- Rows present on both tables but they differ on `qtd_veiculos`.
- Rows on table1 that are not present in table2.
- Rows on table2 that are not present in table1.

If this is the question, the query should be:

```
select j.*, m.*
  from table1 j 
  outer join table2 m on j.uf = m.uf
                     and j.municipio = m.municipio 
                     and j.marca_modelo = m.marca_modelo 
                     and j.ano_fabricacao = m.ano_fabricacao
  where j.qtd_veiculos <> m.qtd_veiculos
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! This query has returned the lines with differences in the last column (qtd_veiculos) but not show the lines of the Table1 that are uniques.